# Casting and accessing attribute of an object using java stream in lesser code

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Can this code be rewritten with a better and more precise way using java stream? I have an array of objects `IModel<?>[] models` and before accessing the attribute in the map I need to cast it to the actual object class.

```
List<String> testStrs = Arrays.stream(models)
.map(item -> {
  TestClass testClass = (TestClass) item;
  return testClass.getStatus();
})
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Note: It is just for personal understanding of streams. Please consider that `IModel<?>[] models` will always have objects of `TestClass` type. I am well aware of how dangerous casting could go if we don't have any proper checks.

Comment: Don't case, it is not type safe?

Comment: `.map(item -> ((TestClass) item).getStatus())`

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShevchenko. I was trying same but didn't think of those round brackets specifically for casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid the intermediate testClass variable.

```
List<String> testStrs = Arrays.stream(models)
.map(item -> ((TestClass) item).getStatus())
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following.  Note I added a instance check to ensure it can cast.  Using method references can increase the clarity of the code.

```
List<String> testStrs 
     = Arrays.stream(models)
             .filter(TestClass.class::isInstance)
             .map(TestClass.class::cast)
             .map(TestClass::getStatus)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```